# Replace negative values and 'blocks" of consecutive zeros up to first positive value in pandas series with NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and I would like to identify all negative values and replace them with NaN. Additionally, all zeros that follow a negative value should be replaced with NaN as well, up until the first positive value occurs.

I think it should be possible to achieve my goal using a for loop over all negative values in the data frame.

For example, for the negative value with index label 1737, I could use something like this:

```py
# list indexes that follow the negative value
indexes = df['counter_diff'].loc[1737:,]
# find first value greater than zero
first_index = next(x for x, val in enumerate(indexes) if val > 0)
```

And then fill the values from index 1737 up to `first_index` with NaN.

However, my dataframe is very large, so I was wondering whether it might be possible to come up with a more computiationally efficient method that leverages pandas.

This is an example of the input:

```py
# input column
In[]
pd.Series({0 : 1, 2 : 3, 3 : -1, 4 : 0, 5 : 0, 7 : 1, 9 : 3, 10 : 0, 11 : -2, 14 : 1})

Out[]
0     1
2     3
3    -1
4     0
5     0
7     1
9     3
10    0
11   -2
14    1
dtype: int64
```

And the desired output:

```py
# desired output
In[]
pd.Series({0 : 1, 2 : 3, 3 : np.nan, 4 : np.nan, 5:np.nan, 7:1, 9:3, 10:0, 11 : np.nan, 14:1})

Out[]
0     1.0
2     3.0
3     NaN
4     NaN
5     NaN
7     1.0
9     3.0
10    0.0
11    NaN
14    1.0
dtype: float64
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) all `0s` and forward fill them with [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html), and check which values in the series are less than `0`. Then use the resulting boolean Series to mask the original Series:

```
s = pd.Series({0 : 1, 2 : 3, 3 : -1, 4 : 0, 5 : 0, 7 : 1, 9 : 3, 10 : 0, 11 : -2, 14 : 1})

s.mask(s.mask(s.eq(0)).ffill().lt(0))

0     1.0
2     3.0
3     NaN
4     NaN
5     NaN
7     1.0
9     3.0
10    0.0
11    NaN
14    1.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great! Do you know whether it is possible to make the ffill conditional on a different column of the row that includes fill value? E.g. only ffill '-1' in column A if column B of that row equals 'a'.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean @hilde I'd suggest you ask this in a new question! Ping me here if you do so :)